# Use one line to get text file content with textscan in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with each line being a string, like:

```
str_a
str_b
str_c
```

if I use `textscan(fid, '%s')`, I will get a 1x1 cell, within which there is another 3x1 cell. Now I would like to use one line code to get this 3x1 cell, how? because I feel the following code is ugly.

```
a = textscan(fid, '%s');
a = a{1};
```

Answer (score 2):

`textscan` is designed to deal with handling input of a complex format with many mixed datatypes. For this reason, it always has a cell array as the output and any strings in your format string are going to be a nested cell array.

An easier way may be to simply forego using `textscan` since you aren't really using the format string. You can use `fread` to read it in as a character array and then split on all of the newlines using `strsplit`

```
a = strsplit(fread(fid, '*char')');
```